# How can I store my form's data in MongoDb via loopback?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, loopbackjs

Here is the format in which I want to store my data:-

```
{
  "profilePicture": "string",
  "firstName": "string",
  "lastName": "string",
  "birthDate": "2017-07-13T10:41:30.618Z",
  "anniversary": "2017-07-13T10:41:30.618Z",
  "contact": [
    "string"
  ],
  "email": [
    "string"
  ],
  "webSite": [
    "string"
  ],
  "address": [
    "string"
  ],
  "location": {},
  "id": "string"
}
```

and for that in my controller I have given the format as follows for the model:-

```
profile = { "location": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      76,
      23
    ]
  },
  "webSite":[],
  "contact":[],
  "email":[],
  "address":[]
};
```

SO how I can use the post method to store the data in above format?